Is it possible to use Python Requests to update a file in a GitHub repo?
I need to update a .txt file on github without using PyGithub. From what I found online about updating files on GitHub using Python Requests, it always returns a 422 error or "TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable"
The code below returns error 422:
payload = {
  "message": "update text.txt",
  "content": "blah",
  "sha": sha
}

r = requests.put('https://api.github.com/repos/<user>/<repo>/contents/text.txt', auth=(user, token), data=json.dumps(payload))
print(r.status_code)

When transcoding I get the error "TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable":
m = "blah"
message_bytes = m.encode("utf-8")
content = base64.b64encode(message_bytes)

payload = {
  "message": "update text.txt",
  "content": content,
  "sha": sha
}

I tried adding «"author": {"name": name,"email": email}» to the payload or completely copying what is there when following the link, but this gives the same result.

The problem is likely sha…?! What is sha?

I’m not sure what exactly sha is responsible for, but in all the examples that I’ve seen it’s used. I used the sha that is available when going to https://api.github.com/repos///contents/text.txt. Without sha the result is the same

sha is a hash created from the content most likely (not familiar with the github api though).   you need to know the hashing function to use then feed the content to it to generate a sha value (assuming I am correctly selecting it use in this context)

GitHub uses git, what you could do is run a git command to commit to that repo you would need to do is use python os.system
